# How to get names of the currently running hadoop jobs?

Tags: hadoop

I need to get the list of job names that currently running, but `hadoop -job list` give me a list of jobIDs.

- Is there a way to get names of the running jobs?
- Is there a way to get the job names from jobIDs?

Answer (score 27):

I've had to do this a number of times so I came up with the following command line that you can throw in a script somewhere and reuse.  It prints the jobid followed by the job name.

```
hadoop job -list | egrep '^job' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "hadoop job -status {} | egrep '^tracking' | awk '{print \$3}'" | xargs -n 1 -I{} sh -c "echo -n {} | sed 's/.*jobid=//'; echo -n ' ';curl -s -XGET {} | grep 'Job Name' | sed 's/.* //' | sed 's/<br>//'"
```

Comment: Nice command.  Although it was a bit sequential and batch-esque for me.  An extreme improvement to this would be to use xargs '-P <num>' max-procs flag, especially with the first xargs that is doing the 'hadoop status -job' command.  I arbitrarily picked <num> (in my case) to be around the average hovering jobs we have on our hadoop cluster.  YMMV.

Comment: The use of `hadoop job -list` appears to be deprecated, the replacement is `mapred job -list`.

Answer (score 14):

If you use Hadoop YARN don't use `mapred job -list` (or its deprecated version `hadoop job -list`) just do

```
yarn application -appStates RUNNING -list
```

That also prints out the application/job name. For mapreduce applications you can get the corresponding `JobId` by replacing the `application` prefix of the `Application-Id` with `job`.

Comment: Protip: I like to use this line (in a script) to get an updated summary of running jobs on the console `watch -n5 "yarn application -appStates RUNNING -list|sed '1d'|cut -f1,2,4,8|column -ts$'\t'"`

Answer (score 3):

Modifying AnthonyF's script, you can use the following on Yarn:

```
mapred job -list 2> /dev/null | egrep '^\sjob' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "mapred job -status {} 2>/dev/null | egrep 'Job File' | awk '{print \$3}'" | xargs -n 1 -I{} sh -c "hadoop fs -cat {} 2>/dev/null | egrep 'mapreduce.job.name' | sed 's/.*<value>//' | sed 's/<\/value>.*//'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop -job -status <jobid>` you will get a *tracking URL* in the output. Going to that URL will give you the tracking page, which has the name

```
Job Name: <job name here>
```

The `-status` command also gives a file, which can also be seen from the *tracking URL*. In this file is a `mapred.job.name` which has the job name.

I didn't find a way to access the job name from the command line. Not to say there isn't... but not found by me. :)

The *tracking URL* and xml *file* are probably your best options for getting the job name.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information in `JobTracker` UI

You can see

```
Jobid
Priority    
User
Name of the job
State of the job whether it succeed or failed
Start Time  
Finish Time 
Map % Complete  
Reduce % Complete etc
```

[INFO](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

Just In case any one interested in latest query to get the Job Name :-). Modified Pirooz Command -

mapred job -list 2> /dev/null | egrep '^job' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "mapred job -status {} 2>/dev/null | egrep 'Job File'" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -n 1 -I{} sh -c "hadoop fs -cat {} 2>/dev/null" | egrep 'mapreduce.job.name' | awk -F"" '{print $2}' | awk -F "" '{print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

I needed to look through history, so I changed `mapred job -list` to `mapred job -list all`....

I ended up adding a `-L` to the curl command, so the block there was:

```
curl -s -L -XGET {}
```

This allows for redirection, such as if the job is retired and in the job history. I also found that it's JobName in the history HTML, so I changed the grep:

```
grep 'Job.*Name'
```

Plus of course changing `hadoop` to `mapred`. Here's the full command:

```
mapred job -list all | egrep '^job' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "mapred job -status {} | egrep '^tracking' | awk '{print \$3}'" | xargs -n 1 -I{} sh -c "echo -n {} | sed 's/.*jobid=//'; echo -n ' ';curl -s -L -XGET {} | grep 'Job.*Name' | sed 's/.* //' | sed 's/<br>//'"
```

(I also changed around the first grep so that I was only looking at a certain username....YMMV)

Answer (score -1):

by typing "jps" in  your terminal .