# Run hive queries, and collect job information

Tags: hadoop, automation, hive

I would like to run a list of generated HIVE queries.
For each, I would like to retrieve the MR job_id (or ids, in case of multiple stages).
And then, with this job_id, collect statistics from job tracker (cumulative CPU, read bytes...)

How can I send HIVE queries from a bash or python script, and retrieve the job_id(s) ?

For the 2nd part (collecting stats for the job), we're using a MRv1 Hadoop cluster, so I don't have the [AppMaster REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/MapredAppMasterRest.html). I'm about to collect data from the jobtracker web UI. Any better idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the list of jobs executed by running this command,

hadoop job -list all

then for each job-id, you can retrieve the stats, using the command,
hadoop job -status job-id

And for associating the jobs with a query, you can get the job_name and match it with the query. 
something like this,
[How to get names of the currently running hadoop jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892495/how-to-get-names-of-the-currently-running-hadoop-jobs)

hope this helps.

Comment: The `hadoop` script has been deprecated in favor of `mapred` so it's best to use the following command now.
`$ mapred job -status job-id`