# How to set custom hadoop job_id?

Tags: hadoop

job_id is `job_local_0001` ,when hadoop jobs is run. I want to set own job_id as `myjobname_001` . Is this possible? How? (My hadoop version: 1.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the job id, but that is what the job name is for. You can change it using:

`job.setJobName("myjob");`

Alongside the job id in the job tracker will be the job name, you can use this to distinguish your jobs.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I try **hadoop job -list** , but i don't see job_name, job_Id visible only. Can I see job_name via any command?

Comment: You can have a look at the answer in this question - might want to note the command down as its a behemoth! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892495/how-to-get-names-of-the-currently-running-hadoop-jobs

Answer (score 0):

According to this code of hadoop for [Click here: JobID.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID.java), you cannot. Hadoop decides it for you.